# Tfidf with a custom list

Tags: tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have a list of raw strings that look like this;

```
listtocheck = ['fadsfsfgblahsdfgsfg','adfaghelloggfg','gagfghellosdfhere','blahsgsdfgsdfhellohsdfhgshstring']
```

and I want to perform TfIdf with these and a list of items I have in a list (not itself).

```
mylist = ['blah','hello','here','string']
```

This list I am vectorising as such;

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer = 'char_wb', ngram_range=(2,3))
listvec = tf.fit_transform(mylist)
```

This gives me the tfidf of the things in `mylist`. What I would like to be able to go is to check the number of times that the ngrams from `mylist` appear in each item of `listtocheck` and then perform TfIdf based on the total number times that ngram appears in all of the strings in `listtocheck`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this I had to first `.fit()` on `mylist` but then `.transform()` on `listtocheck`.

Here is the code I used in the end:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

def create_vec(listtocheck,mylist):

    tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer = 'char_wb',ngram_range=(2,3))
    tf.fit(mylist)
    X = tf.transform(listtocheck)

    return X

vecs = create_vec(listtocheck, mylist)
```